# Django loading static url and path from template

Tags: python, django

I need to link a href tag in Django template..The file is located in a static location under folder product-images..The actual filename is located in the db...

So,basically it need to load product-images/book1.jpg...How can I concatenate productinfo.link with product-images/..The below code is not working..

```
<a href="{% static "product-images/" {{productinfo.link}} %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<a href="{% static "product-images/" %}{{productinfo.link}}">
```

You may need

```
<a href="{% static "product-images/" %}{{ productinfo.link|safe }}">
```

to avoid html escaping